# CSS Horizontal Page Squashing

Tags: html, css, overflow

Basically I simply want to make it so that this website

NO LINK

doesn't get squashed when you make the page smaller than the elements that have been defined. However I want the elements to remain at the exact same size they are at, for obvious design issues. Therefore I need a simple horizontal scroll bar or something, but when I've messed with such a design it doesn't seem to make much difference. If you need any coding, or have any questions.. Feel free to ask.

If you notice when you make the page smaller in the horizontal margin, the sidebar gets shoved into the main content. That is one of the main issues, and I figured it would be a good idea to point it out. Just to show part of the problem.

ANSWER

```
#Wrapper{
overflow: auto;
z-index: 6;
min-height: 1400px;
width: 100%;
min-width:1400px; <--- Added that to make sure that the content never gets squashed.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could tell your sidebar to be always posioned next to your main container. To do that you need first of all to give a class name to this div:

```
<div style="padding-bottom:15px;">
    <p align="center"><font size="+2">SITE UNDER CONSTRUCTION</font></p>
    ....
</div>
```

Once you do that you need to put your #Sidebar inside that div to get something like this:

```
<div class="mycontentclass">

    <div id="Sidebar">
        <div style="margin-left:5px;">
            <a href="http://carnal.ueteribus.com/">Home</a><br>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>

    <p align="center"><font size="+2">SITE UNDER CONSTRUCTION</font></p>
    ....

</div>
```

And then in your CSS styles you need to add:

```
.mycontentclass{
    padding-bottom: 15px; //This is the attribute you defined inline before setting a class for you div
    position: relative;
}

#Sidebar{
    position: absolute;
    left: -205px; //Sidebar width + gutter between the content
}
```

And now your menu won't go over your content, it'll stay always next to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used to fix the problem.

```
#Wrapper{
overflow: auto;
z-index: 6;
min-height: 1400px;
width: 100%;
min-width:1400px; <--- Added that to make sure that the content never gets squashed.
}
```